# Facebook Graph API get original picture size not working

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Need some help to get a normal or larger image from posts using  the Facebook Graph API, at the moment it only gives a 130 x 130 px image in the object.

```js
function fbFetch() {

    var access_token = "";
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=intel&fields=posts.limit(5){message,created_time,picture.type(normal)}&access_token=' + access_token;

    $.getJSON(url, function(response) {

        var messages = [];

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(response).forEach(function(page, idx, array) {
            response[page].posts.data.forEach(function(post, idx, array) {
                messages.push(post);
            });
        });

        function compare(a, b) {
            if (a.created_time < b.created_time)
                return -1;
            if (a.created_time > b.created_time)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        var html = "<ul>";
        $.each(messages.sort(compare), function(i, fb) {
            if (typeof fb.picture != "undefined") {
                html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + '<img SRC="' + fb.picture + '">' + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
            } else {
                html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
            }
        });
        html += "</ul>";
        $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
    });
}

fbFetch();
```

```html
<div class="facebookfeed"></div>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6fhq3dat/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `full_picture` instead of `picture`

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=intel&fields=posts.limit(3){message,created_time,full_picture}&access_token=" + access_token;
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fhq3dat/18/)**